# Two textbox synchronized update

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, binding

I have two textbox in wpf first one is for grams and second one is for mililiters. I need to update the second if user enter something to another one and lost focus. It should work grams -> ml and ml -> grams, but I have problem with property changed because update one of them cause trigger property changed on second one so it recalcute again and overwrite previous value. I hope you understand what I need. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: could you post the code you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the setter of your properties you can throw a PropertyChanged for the other Properties you want to update. You can also call an method in the setters that do some calculating and throws  that PropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

In your binding set

> UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus

.I think its happening because in your binding

> UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

.I hope this will help.